# Recpatcha not rendering until refresh page in Angular js

Tags: single-page-application, recaptcha

**Recaptcha not rendering until I refresh the page**

I'm using Recaptcha in my angular js project for security stuff.
I just implemented the captcha with following below steps:
1. I added below link  to my page (in the head tag before every styles and scripts file):

```
   <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=fa" async ></script>
```

2. In my form, I added captcha

```
 <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my_site_key"></div>
```

so my page is something like this

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>reCAPTCHA demo: Simple page</title>
       <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=fa" async ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="?" method="POST">
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my_site_key"></div>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Apparently, everything is fine, but Recaptcha not rendering until I refresh the page. actually, it's not gonna work when the page request by ajax but after page reloading, Recaptcha will render on the page!

So how can I render Recaptcha with the first render??

Comment: Similar problem (duplicate?): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630534/google-nocaptcha-recaptcha-only-shows-up-on-refresh-in-angular-spa#answer-28942332

Answer (score 0):

I figure out how can I fix this problem.
instead of adding this script

```
 <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=fa" async ></script>
```

to layout page, I added it in every page that I want to render captcha so after routing to the special page, in addition, to render the page content captcha will render for us too.

for exmaple the content page template will be something like this:

contactus.html content

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=fa" async></script>
<form name="contactUsForm" novalidate>
    <section class="well">

        <div class="form-horizontal form-widgets col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="{'has-error': contactUsForm.firstName.$error.required && contactUsForm.firstName.$dirty, 'has-success': !contactUsForm.firstName.$error.required }">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="firstName">Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" ng-model="contactUs.firstName" class="form-control" ng-class="{'form-control-error': contactUsForm.firstName.$error.required && contactUsForm.firstName.$dirty, 'form-control-success': !contactUsForm.firstName.$error.required }" placeholder="Name" required />
                    <span ng-show="contactUsForm.firstName.$error.required && contactUsForm.firstName.$dirty" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span ng-show="!contactUsForm.firstName.$error.required" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <div class="text-danger" ng-show="contactUsForm.firstName.$error.required && contactUsForm.firstName.$dirty">Name is required</div>
                </div>
            </div>      
        <div class="form-horizontal form-widgets col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-2" style="display: flex;justify-content: flex-start;margin-bottom: 2rem;">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my-sitekey"></div> <!-- Server -->
            <!--<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my-sitekey"></div>--> <!-- Local -->
        </div>
        <div class="buttons-wrap col-sm-offset-2" style="text-align:right;padding-right:1.6rem">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="contactUsForm.$invalid" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmModal"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></i><span>&submit</span></button>
        </div>

    </section>
</form>
```